# Grep for hard drive id on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal, grep

OS X 10.8.2

I want to find out what `/dev/disks*` is for the mountpoint `/`

So I run `$ df -lak /`

and I get:

`Filesystem   1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   487546976 332107020 155183956    69% 83090753 38795989   68%   /`

so what do I add to the command to get the `/dev/disk0s2` piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df / | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'` will do the trick, if you're just looking for something quick and dirty.